# Validation that .NET/C# generated webservice proxy client object is connected to the right object on the server side

Tags: c#, web-services, validation, version

I create c# proxy client class by

```
svcutil.exe WSDL
```

add this class to the project and use it as any other class.
During development cycle WSDL as well as server side changes and connection fails.

Is there way how I can be sure that client class on my side matches server side?
Preferably inside program.

Please, do not provide suggestions that I have to regenerate and recompile. It takes some time and during this time server can change.

Another suggestion to "manually" validate that all methods match as well as their signatures does not work either. It could be the same signatures but class is different. For example, each service has method GetVersion() and it returns latest version but client shows this latest version from server side when actual client side class is few versions old.

Comment: does it *have* to be the created proxy class? could you, for example, create your own proxy at runtime in the client?

Comment: First of all it does not help me to determine that server side is changed. Second - unfortunately for me it should be generated class. I do not want to mess with all security, delivery and other features - I hope generated class should take care of it - not me.